# MULTIPART_STRICT_ERROR marking product upload in magento as malicous

Tags: magento, mod-security, multipartform-data

I am running a magento installation for one of my client and the server there has modSecurity installed.

While I was trying to upload the products, I have been getting the following error.

```
Match of "eq 0" against "MULTIPART_STRICT_ERROR" required. [file "/usr/local/apache/conf/modsec2.conf"] [line "15"] [id "1500860"] [msg "Multipart request body failed strict validation: PE 0, BQ 0, BW 0, DB 0, DA 0, HF 0, LF 0, SM 0, IQ 1, IP , IH 0, FL 0"] [hostname "newsite.gogifts.in"] [uri "/index.php/admin/catalog_product_gallery/upload/key/8a40202b18c590f502a1ea9553813319/"]
```

It is a shared hosting server and hence I am unable to change any settings at the apache level.

Can someone help me with this?
Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: How do you upload the products - what format do you use, what kind of data do you upload (text, files, images, etc.), what tool do you use to upload (Magento import/export, custom tool, browser, etc.)?

Comment: I'm trying to upload from the standard product upload interface itself

Comment: Did you check if the file you are trying to upload has a correct file extension? I've seen lot's of issues when ie. people where working with jpeg files which didn't have .jpg extension and this caused all sorts of problems on different machines.

Comment: So what are you calling "uploading products" - creation it via Catalog -> Manage Products -> New products? Or do you import them via Import/Export?

Answer (score 4):

The list in the error shows what it have reacted to, in this case IQ (MULTIPART_INVALID_QUOTING).

> PE 0, BQ 0, BW 0, DB 0, DA 0, HF 0, LF 0, SM 0, IQ 1, IP , IH 0, FL 0

Did you have a quote character in your filename? e.g. some'file.txt. 
You can ask the shared hosting provider if they can loosen their policy.

Here is the list of what the abbreviations mean:
https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual-(v2.x)#MULTIPART_STRICT_ERROR

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered this **Match of 'eq 0' against 'MULTIPART_STRICT_ERROR required** in my project.

**How is this error caused?**
This error is caused by mod_security blocking a potentially malicious upload. While it may be completely harmless, mod_security has no way of knowing if it is harmless or not.
Typically, the content in question is a file being uploaded which contains a special character such as a single or double quote within the file name which is often used by attackers to inject malicious scripts into websites.

**How do I resolve the issue?**
Simply put, rename the file to remove the offending special character from the file name
or (disable this security rule in /etc/{path}/mod_security.conf by commenting the line " SecRule MULTIPART_STRICT_ERROR "!@eq 0" \" or by .htaccess file - NOT RECOMMENDED AT ALL)

Comment: not recommended but how it can be fixed ? Apache is block my request entirely, in Python I can change the filename before I save to disk, but if Apache is blocking me - I can't even do that, so what's the other option ? notify the user is not possible as they are uploading from mobile